# pthread_mutex_unlock_drop crashes with abort

Tags: c, multithreading, pthreads

I'm trying to debug an abort crash in a project. The stack trace (on Mac OS X) is as follows:

> Thread[25] EXC_CRASH (SIGABRT) (0x0000000000000000,
>   0x0000000000000000) [  0] 0x00007fff8d439f06 __pthread_kill + 10 [  1]
>   0x00007fff86b504eb libsystem_pthread.dylib'pthread_kill + 89 [  2]
>   0x00007fff9833d6e7 abort + 129 [  3] 0x00007fff86b51320
>   libsystem_pthread.dylib'__pthread_abort + 48 [  4] 0x00007fff86b513d4
>   libsystem_pthread.dylib'__pthread_abort_reason + 179 [  5]
>   0x00007fff86b4ddf0 libsystem_pthread.dylib'_pthread_mutex_unlock_drop
>   + 160 [  6] 0x000000010a0b3624 AppName'TinyThreadObj::mutex::unlock() + 20 at tinythread.h:292 [  7] 0x000000010a0b35fc AppName'TinyThreadObj::lock_guard<
>   TinyThreadObj::mutex>::~lock_guard() + 44 at tinythread.h:433 [  8]
>   0x000000010a0acd24
>   AppName::lock_guard::~lock_guard() + 20 at
>   tinythread.h:430 [  9] 0x000000010a0955a7 AppName`FunctionName1(void*)
>   + 4519 at ClassName1.cpp:2387

How do I debug it to see how the mutex might  be getting invalid. It doesn't seems like it should just looking at the code. But I'm not able to produce it in debugger. It's mac os x libpthread lib.

Comment: all you have is the stack trace? Some code might help if you think you've got it narrowed down to a problematic area

Comment: I cannot provide code. Is there a way for me to find out if mutex is valid for debug logs?

Comment: You should reduce the problem to the smallest reproducible code and post the code of `lock_guard`.

Comment: Tough to help without code. A stack trace is just that; a stack trace.  All we (and I suppose you) know is it crashed at ClassName1.cpp line 2387 in `FunctionName1(void*)` at offset 4519 if I'm reading that correctly. This is helpful in pointing out _where_ the problem occurred, but not in discerning _what_ the problem is until you look there. If you simply don't have access to the code, you need to tell whoever gave you this to do their own debugging. I can understand if its proprietary code, but in that case follow szym's suggestion. There's nothing secret about `pthreads`.

Comment: but, having said that ,, not sure what you mean by "mutex is valid for debug logs". `pthread_mutex_t` types have to be initialized before they are used, either statically at declaration using `PTHREAD_MUTEX_INITIALIZER` or dynamically with the `pthread_mutex_init()` function. If you don't do that, I'm sure all kinds of UB ensues. This is a good `pthreads` tutorial, perhaps make sure you're following the structure in their examples? Good luck: https://computing.llnl.gov/tutorials/pthreads/